# Errors in form for php

Tags: php

I have been working on this form for my php class. I can not believe I am getting errors left and right. Now I am getting this error:

No database selected
error on table connection

But i check and everything works on my table, here is my code:

```
if ($_POST['submit']!=""){
if ($_POST['username']==""||$_POST['password1']==""||$_POST['password2']==""||$_POST['firstname']==""||$_POST['lastname']==""||$_POST['address']==""||$_POST['email']==""||$_POST['city']==""||$_POST['state']==""||$_POST['zip']==""||$_POST['phone']=="");
$error=1;
  }
        else if ($_POST['password1']!=$_POST['password2']){
    $error=2;
   }
else{
$hostname="localhost";
$database="Contacts";
$mysql_login="Web_User";
$mysql_password="my1230";

if (!($db = mysql_connect($hostname, $mysql_login , $mysql_password))){
    echo "error on connect";
}
   else{
  if (!(mysql_select_db($databse,$db))){
    echo mysql_error();
    echo "<br>error on table connection";
}
   else{
    $SQL="Insert into tblUsers(username,password,firstname,lastname,email,address,city,state,zip, phone,signupDate)values)'".$_POST['username']."',PASSWORD('".$_POST['password1']."'),'".$_POST['firstname']."','".$_POST['lastname']."','".$_POST['address']."','".$_POST['city']."','".$_POST['state']."','".$_POST['zip']."','".$_POST['phone']."',NOW())";
    mysql_query($SQL);
    if (is_numeric(mysql_insert_id())){
        header("Location:member-content.php?name=".$_POST['username']);
    }
    else{
        echo "Sorry, there was an errot.Please try again ot contact the administrator";
    }
    mysql_close($db);//closeing out connection,done for now
  }
}
```

}

?>

I haven been sittin here and when I get one thing working the next thing don't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled database in this line: `mysql_select_db($databse,$db)`

Comment: That work now it wont even bring up the form it goes to the content page.. but thanks

Comment: Bring up what form? It appears like the content page is the final destination to this `PHP` script.

Comment: well that error was on my form.php if you go to the site and you are not register you can register but when you click on that link it takes you to the content page. Something is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

change :

```
if (!(mysql_select_db($databse,$db))){
```

by :

```
if (!(mysql_select_db($database,$db))){
```